# ChromeDriver - getText cause the button to click in debug mode

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using chromedriver and try to locate button that found on popup.

When I try using xpath it return nothing but on IE it works.

So I try using class name and then loop on all buttons and find the one with text "OK".
I got Exception "org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document" from the b.getText() command
and I see that the button was clicked.

```
    List<WebElement> all = Test1.driver.findElements(By
            .className("btn-primary"));

    for (WebElement b : all) {
        if (b.getText().trim().equals("OK")) {
            b.click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code has the potential for throwing StaleReference exceptions all over the place, considering it's doing a `.click`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that there's maybe another 'Ok'-button which was clicked by chromedriver?
Chromedriver is way faster than IEdriver, so there might be a StaleElementReferenceException, even if there's no Exception in Iedriver.
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp

I would suggest to make a step backward. If findElements works with 'By.className' then it should also work with 'By.xpath'. You mentioned, the button is generated, so do you already use explicite or implicite waitmethods? IEDriver maybe is slow enough, but chromedriver might be way to fast, so chromedriver doesn't find the button, because it's simply not jet in the dom.
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits

for your case, I recommand the 'visibilityOf'-Condition:
https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement)

I hope this helps, if not, please don't hesitate to ask further.